# Problem parsing a String with a letter and a number to an Integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a table which adds rows by add button.
When a new row is added to the table the 'process column' which starts at P0 should be parsed to an integer and 1 should be added to the process of the last row. However this only works for one process after that it displays PNaN. What in the code could be causing this problem? Thanks

```
<div class="container inline">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table" id="configTable">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Process</th>
          <th scope="col">Arrival Time</th>
          <th scope="col">Burst Time</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantum</th>
          <th scope="col">Priority</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">P0</th>
          <td>0</td>
          <td><input autofocus class="burstTime" type="number" min="1" max="15"></td>
          <td><input class="quantumTime" type="number" min="1" max="10"></td>
          <td><input class="priorityTime" type="number" min="1" max="10"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow();">
    <input id="del" type="button" value="-" onclick="deleteRow();">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
//ADD NEW ROW
function addRow() {
  var lastRow = $('table tr:last');
  var lastProcessNumber = parseInt(lastRow.children()[0].innerText);

  var newRow = '<tr><th>P'
  + (lastProcessNumber + 1)
  + '</td><td><input class="arrivalTime" type="number"/>'
  + '</td><td><input class="burstTime" type="number"/></td>'
  + '</td><td><input class="quantumTime" type="number"/></td>'
  + '</td><td><input class="priorityTime" type="number"/></td>'

  lastRow.after(newRow);
```

Comment: `<th>'+ P# +'</td>' <= mismatching closure tag.  Voting to close as a typo

Comment: My fault in code replication, problem persists even with matching tags

Comment: Commonly the NaN is due to an operation that could not be performed either because one of the operands was non-numeric or the result of the operation is non-numeric, so from tour code lastProcessNumber should be the source of the issue.

Comment: Just a comment, you can check the Template literals for your long strings: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified *radix*, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. `parseInt` truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

Replace the character `P` with empty string:

```
var lastProcessNumber = parseInt(lastRow.children()[0].innerText.replace('P',''));
```

```js
//ADD NEW ROW
function addRow() {
  var lastRow = $('table tr:last');
  var lastProcessNumber = parseInt(lastRow.children()[0].innerText.replace('P',''));
  var newRow = '<tr><th>P'
  + (lastProcessNumber + 1)
  + '</td><td><input class="arrivalTime" type="number"/>'
  + '</td><td><input class="burstTime" type="number"/></td>'
  + '</td><td><input class="quantumTime" type="number"/></td>'
  + '</td><td><input class="priorityTime" type="number"/></td>'

  lastRow.after(newRow)
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container inline">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table" id="configTable">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Process</th>
          <th scope="col">Arrival Time</th>
          <th scope="col">Burst Time</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantum</th>
          <th scope="col">Priority</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">P0</th>
          <td>0</td>
          <td><input autofocus class="burstTime" type="number" min="1" max="15"></td>
          <td><input class="quantumTime" type="number" min="1" max="10"></td>
          <td><input class="priorityTime" type="number" min="1" max="10"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow();">
    <input id="del" type="button" value="-" onclick="deleteRow();">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `P` in the innerText and it's preventing `parseInt()` from parsing correctly.

Replace anything in your text that not a number with the empty string so `parseInt()` works.

This

```
var lastProcessNumber = parseInt(lastRow.children()[0].innerText);
```

becomes

```
var lastProcessNumber = parseInt(lastRow.children()[0].innerText.replace(/[^\d]/,''));
```

https://jsbin.com/vizazinewe/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Works perfectly too!

Comment: @Jarred If mine "worked perfectly" and I posted mine first, why did you select a different post as the answer?

Comment: Probably the reason you mentioned is not clear and sufficient to OP.....

Comment: @Mamun I would prefer an answer from him.

Comment: The answer provided by @Mamun was cleaner and more precise but both approaches work so thank you for your help, if I could upvote two I would.

Answer (score 1):

**Working fiddle:** https://jsbin.com/zizayoyufu/2/edit?js,console,output

Your JS adjusted to work:

```
//ADD NEW ROW
function addRow() {
  var lastRow = $('table tr:last');
  const processField = lastRow.children()[0].innerText;
  const processIdRegex = new RegExp("\\d+");
  let processId = 0;

  if(processIdRegex.test(processField)) {
    processId = parseInt(processField.match(processIdRegex)[0]);
  }

  var lastProcessNumber = processId;

  var newRow = '<tr><th>P'
  + (lastProcessNumber + 1)
  + '</td><td><input class="arrivalTime" type="number"/>'
  + '</td><td><input class="burstTime" type="number"/></td>'
  + '</td><td><input class="quantumTime" type="number"/></td>'
  + '</td><td><input class="priorityTime" type="number"/></td>'

  lastRow.after(newRow);
}
```

`parseInt` returns `NaN` if the first character encoutered is string.